# response undefined when calling google api thru emberjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3, ember.js, autocomplete

I am trying to call google api for getting place suggestions from ember js. like below: this is the service module

```
fetch(){
let url=`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=IL&types=geocode&key=API_KEY`
return Ember.RSVP.resolve(Ember.$.ajax(url,{
method: 'GET'
}))
.then(
(response)=>{
console.log("google suggested places:",response);
return response;
})
```

*the above url when served with API_KEY and pasted in browser, a JSON response is returned with the suggested places.

also, i am seeing JSON response in newtwork tab of developer tools but the .then is not able to capture that resonse, **and printing in console as response undefined.**

ref : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_results

And in console i am seeing " Failed to load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=IL&types=geocode&key=API_KEY: No 'Access-control-Allow_origin'header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [`Ember.RSVP.resolve`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.17/classes/rsvp/methods/resolve?anchor=resolve) wrong. It returns a `Promise` which resolves immediately with value passed as first argument. So in your case it resolves with return value of `Ember.$ajax()`. I'm not quite sure if this function exists. I guess you meant `Ember.$.ajax()` which is just an alias for [`jQuery.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). But this one should return a [`jqXHR` object](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR). So I have no idea why your code is not throwing for `Ember.$ajax()` is not a function or why `response` is `undefined` and not a `jqXHR` object.

But nevertheless your approach to wrap the ajax call in a promise is wrong. Also I would say using jQuery.ajax is not best practice. There are some work ongoing to make jQuery optional in ember.js and you don't want to couple your application with it.

I would recommend using [ember-fetch](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-fetch) or [ember-ajax](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax).

Comment: it was a typo , i was using $.ajax only, edited in the main content too.

Comment: Well, i tried to use ember-ajax and still getting the same error, i am able to see the response in network tab but this error still persists 
 " Failed to load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=IL&types=geocode&key=API_KEY: No 'Access-control-Allow_origin'header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
 and this is stopping from getting the response out ( i mean even in console)

Comment: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue related to Google Map API is a completely other question. Please open another question for that issue. Have a look in [docs provided by Google for CORS](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors) to get started.

Comment: opened another thread :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47835147/google-auto-complete-cors-issue-when-called-from-ember

Answer (score 0):

The above approach doesnt work, so for any who wants to have maps suggestions on ember application , follow this 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-g-maps

It is perfectly working.